# how to map netcdf data ob base map

Tags: geospatial, google-colaboratory, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4

file contains values of echos w.r.t to lat/long, I have to plot complete range of echos over base map.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
upload = files.upload()
my_example_nc_file = 'a.nc'
fh = Dataset(my_example_nc_file, mode='r')
lons = fh.variables['longitude'][:]
lats = fh.variables['latitude'][:]
ech= fh.variables['echos'][:]

from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
m = Basemap(width=5000000,height=3500000,
        resolution='l',projection='stere',\
        lat_ts=40,lat_0=lat_0,lon_0=lon_0)

xi, yi = m(lons, lats)
#simple plot
#m.plot(xi, yi, 'co')
m.scatter(rge,yi, marker = 'o', color='r', zorder=5)
```

Current code execute below results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK6q4.png)
I want to plot total echos with variation represented by colors as presented in below screen short

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAXr5.png)

Comment: It is difficult to help without access to the data file.

Comment: The problem is resolved... Do you have any idea how to access local directory and process all files withen